# Slide and change position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a very simple slideshow just for the learning purpose. I want to slide the list items to the left automatically in a loop.

I have come up with following code, it slides but I am unable to set the correct position for the slide (as it only flashes and disappears). Check the demo to see the problem:

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32v5q59L/)

**Html:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var width         = $('li').width();
var totalWidth    = $('li').length * width;
var count         = $('li').length;
var first         = $('li').eq(0);
var last          = $('li').eq(count-1);

$('ul').css({
    'width'     : totalWidth
});


first.addClass('active');

var start = function() {            
    target = $('.active').index();       
    target === last ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
    nextSlide(target);          
};

var nextSlide = function(target) {
    //console.log(target);
    $('.active').animate({'left':'-'+ width*target +'px'},300);
    $('li').removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
};

setInterval(function () {
                start();
            }, 3000)
```

Comment: just a question why you didn't use an library (Jquery plugin for exemple) you can find a lot ?

Comment: i'm just trying to learn jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have changed `Class name` only and it works. You was using wrong class `active` for animation, instead of this you should animation your complete `<ul>` so i have used class of ul `list` for left animation:

What i have changed:

```
$('.active').animate({'left':'-'+ width*target +'px'},300);
```

to

```
$('.list').animate({'left':'-'+ width*target +'px'},300);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/32v5q59L/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you notice that after last slide, it doesn't go directly to the first slider, there is some gap. Do you know what would be causing that?

Comment: For last slide, change `target === last ? target = 0 : target = target+1;` to `target === last.index() ? target = 0 : target = target+1;`: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/32v5q59L/2/

Comment: @Manwal this actualy slides an extra empty slide

Answer (score 3):

your problem is you don not understand where your li's are actually positioned
on way to solve it is to just slide the ul like so:

```
function slide(){
    $('ul').animate({'left':$('ul').position().left - width},300);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32v5q59L/5/

Comment: Your effort appreciated but, See sliding after last slide. It stops sliding. :(

Comment: you never said you whanted a carusel